# ins SpriteKit, "select" all the sprites my finger touches while moving

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

So I'm trying to learn SpriteKit while building what I think is a simple puzzle game. I have a 5x5 grid of SKSpriteNodes of different colors. What I want is to be able to touch one, and move my finger horizontally or vertically and detect all the nodes that my finger is touching, like if I was "selecting" them.

I tried to do something like this, but it crashes the app:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKSpriteNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    NSLog(@"Dragged over: %@", node);
}
```

Is there something like a "touchEnter" / "touchLeave" kinda event that I'm missing? Sorry, I don't even know what I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIPanGestureRecognizer` is your friend:

```
 -(void)didMoveToView:(SKView*)view {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPangestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
 }
 -(void)hadlePangesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
    SKSpriteNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:[self convertPointFromView:location]];
    if (node) {
        NSLog(@"Dragged over: %@", node);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the "SKSpriteNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:[self convertPointFromView:location]];" be an SKNode.

Comment: This works well when there is only one touch, but not when there is a second touch holding down elsewhere on the screen.