# Select the sprites i touch with my finger using nodeAtPoint does not select sprites

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, sprite-kit

I have two sprites added onto _background (green) and is trying to select the sprites by dragging the finger over them.

```
[_background addChild:S1];
[_background addChild:S2];
```

[image]

I am using the method from this question: [select all the sprites my finger touches while moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234718/ins-spritekit-select-all-the-sprites-my-finger-touches-while-moving)

I do not get a hit on the actual spaceship sprites, only the background.

The code i use:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    _touchLocation = [sender locationInView:sender.view];
    _touchLocation = [self convertPointFromView:_touchLocation];

...

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
                NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan");
                //////Make sure that no sprites are moved during the selecting phase//////
                _background.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
                NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged");
                SKNode *node = [_background nodeAtPoint:[self convertPointFromView:_touchLocation]];
                //if (![node.name isEqualToString:@"background"]) {
                    NSLog(@"Selected node:%@", node.name);
                //}
            } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
                NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
                _background.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            }
...
```

The result:

```
2014-01-05 21:38:34.011 xxxxx[21172:a0b] UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan
2014-01-05 21:38:36.513 xxxxx[21172:a0b] UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged
2014-01-05 21:38:36.514 xxxxx[21172:a0b] Selected node:background
2014-01-05 21:38:36.545 xxxxx[21172:a0b] UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged
2014-01-05 21:38:36.546 xxxxx[21172:a0b] Selected node:background
2014-01-05 21:38:36.578 xxxxx[21172:a0b] UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged
2014-01-05 21:38:36.579 xxxxx[21172:a0b] Selected node:background
…
2014-01-05 21:38:36.987 xxxxx[21172:a0b] UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
```

I am not able to get a hit on the spaceships when i move my fingers over them.

**How i created the UIPanGestureRecognizer**

```
_panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:_panGesture];
```

Comment: show me code how do you create UIPanGestureRecognizer object?

Comment: Seriously!! If i doing such task in cocos2d then i will not be work with gestureRecognizer kind of stuff. Cocos2d given us cctouches events methods for detecting images on touch. See this tut for reference http://www.raywenderlich.com/2343/cocos2d-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites

Comment: Thanks Reformer but I am not using Cocos2d this time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this at the start of the method:

```
_touchLocation = [self convertPointFromView:_touchLocation];
```

And you do it again later on:

```
SKNode *node = [_background nodeAtPoint:[self convertPointFromView:_touchLocation]];
```

My guess is that converting the point twice may give you the wrong location. You should log the points to see that they're about correct.

If not that, then perhaps you need to convert the location to the ship parent's node space. As follows:

```
_touchLocation = [_background convertPoint:_touchLocation toNode:_background];
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.